# best backbone.js and require.js boilerplate for huge apps

Tags: backbone.js, boilerplate

i'm looking for a good backbone.js + require.js boiler plate for my app as this will give me a good idea of how to modularize my code and get me started. i'm using backbone.js-AMD-Boilerplate ( [link](https://github.com/david0178418/BackboneJS-AMD-Boilerplate) ) but i'm not sure if there is some other boiler plate better than this.
i don't want to indulge myself more into any other loader or framework to keep things simple for my project.
i'm in the beginning so i'm just focusing on backbone.js and require.js ( text.js to load my html templates ).
need your opinions on this guyz
thnx

Comment: have you looked at http://boilerplatejs.org ?

Comment: didn't heard of it.looking it right now

Comment: @Hasith i looked at boilerplatejs.org. It is good but it is not exactly according to my requirements. it uses too much of other libraries + i just need a boilerplate for backbonejs and require.js so that i don't have to learn too much extra stuff in the start. After i have good understanding and working experience with backbone & require, i'll easily be able to code my self.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be the most popular [backbone boilerplate](https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone-boilerplate)...

With regards to requirejs you may reconsider against using any module loader until your app is past its initial stages and you indeed have many modules - it is much easier to develop/debug this way and it is not difficult to add a module loader later as long as you avoid using globals and encapsulate your modules in `function () { ... your module ... }`.

That is only my personal opinion that probably will not be supported by people who have forgotten how it was when you're just starting to use module loaders ;)

Comment: The above linked backbone boilerplate is very useful indeed...

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find more comprehensive solution with up-to-date dependencies, latest bugfixes and useful examples included.

(Backbone + CoffeeScript + Browserify + SASS/SCSS + Image-min + Jasmine) x Grunt

https://github.com/antarasi/backbone-boilerplate