# Reduction of CPU utilization on a nodejs server

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-applications, linkedin-api, express

I am looking into interesting ways to reduce CPU utilization
on a NodeJS server.

During my research I have found the following article: 
http://engineering.linkedin.com/nodejs/blazing-fast-nodejs-10-performance-tips-linkedin-mobile

These are all excellent tips but I have a question regarding
hint#4.

Does this really mean a user is requesting "JavaScriptTemplate.html"
and then all the JSON is requested subsequently (which is not implemented here)?

Assuming that all the dynamic content should be available without user
interaction (e.g. requesting JSON on a button click event) what is
the best way to achive this? I can think of loading additional JS dependencies
(requirejs) where functions are executed to request the JSON stuff.

Since I never see big websites to call static html files but
instead requesting routes to their application servers how common
is the solution suggested by the link above? Do they really 
use server side templates to waste CPU utilization on 
mostly static text content???

For Node (expressJS) this must be a suboptimal way especially 
if the HTML to be produced is fairly complex... ideally
Node should just operate as an API server providing JSON data.

Do you have some ideas to share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for sharing the post - it is a great one (and very timely for me).

You're actually asking two questions - 1) how to load data to render html client-side without client interaction and 2) how to send a static file to a browser when user actually requests a route.

### Rendering page without user interaction and my ¢2 on client MVC

1) You need to run all the initialisation/data-loading/rendering code to render the page after the page has been loaded. If you use jQuery in the client (as most web applications do):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Your code here
});
```

It's just copied from [jQuery docs](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works#Launching_Code_on_Document_Ready).

Most folks use backbone/underscore to build MVC layer in the client. Although there are a lot of much fancier (and seemingly more powerful) client-side frameworks to do so, this couple gives you just enough power without limiting your options or reducing your flexibility you will definitely need at some point. Underscore (which is backbone dependency anyway) in addition to many very useful functions (you will be surprised what's possible with JavaScript if you spend one hour to read through the whole one page manual) has its own templates which are deceptively simple and at the same time extremely powerful as they just run all javascript inside templates.

Although it is usually a bad thing to have the application logic in templates (as underscore allows and most fancier and "more powerful" templating engines don't), it is often very handy and much better to be able to add some logic in template when you discover yourself in some tight corner (as you often will) than to redesign a lot of application logic or add additional templates.

Also, my opinion is to avoid using require.js or any other module loader (until you really must use them) as I wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14037727/best-backbone-js-and-require-js-boilerplate-for-huge-apps/14041967#14041967).

### Serving static html for any route and nginx config for node-as-api

2) You need to rewrite requests to all routes to respond with the same static html file (or several route-dependent html files). Depending on your preferences or application requirements it can be the file with an empty body (in which case users will see a blank page until your data is loaded and page is rendered/inserted in body), some welcome page or even some template page where instead of data a spinning wheel is shown.

The way you rewrite requests depends on the web server you use to serve static content and to proxy requests. If you use Apache (an unlikely choice with Node, as it is synchronous) you need to use .htaccess files. If you use Nginx as most folks using node do, you need to use rewrite directive inside server block in config file like it is done in example below:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com;
    root         html/example;

    access_log   logs/example.log;

    # location block below sends specific static assets from inside your app's
    # public directory when routes /img, /js, /css, /views are requested
    location ~ /(img|js|css|views)/ {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /public/$1 break;
    }

    # location block below proxies all data requests (/api route) to your node app
    location /api {
        proxy_pass             http://localhost:3000/;
        proxy_redirect         http://localhost:3000/ http://example.com;
        proxy_connect_timeout  30s;
        proxy_read_timeout     30s;
        proxy_cookie_domain    localhost example.com;
        #proxy_http_version     1.1;
    }

    # location block below rewrites all other routes to a specific html file
    # that is sent to the client and that is supposed to load all JS and
    # static assets to render a page
    location / {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /public/app.html;
    }
}
```

The way you render a page in the client (and the data you request from the server to do so) will depend on the route the user requested (which you can access/change in javascript as well as you can set/access/change cookies). All the navigation inside application (when the user clicks any buttons or internal links - you need to catch all click events) happens without additional requests for pages or static assets that are already loaded, only data requests are sent to the server.

I hope it helps.

### SEO Update

The suggested configuration for nginx is suitable only if you don't need any pages indexed by robots and visible to other web apps that need your static htmls, like facebook, e.g. For pages that you want to be indexed, you need to add conditions to route requests from robots differently (based on $http_user_agent) and also render some static htmls for those routes. But it can be a different purely semantic html (smaller, without design images, layout divs/classes, UI elements and javascript to reduce requests from crawling robots and web apps).

Comment: Thanks for your hard work. Awesome answer!

1: jquery's ready() is great but now all these nice framworks like angular are coming up and I am planing 
to use one of them to handle such stuff.

2: A small misunderstanding here. My real concern is
coming from the impression that a lot of pages use server
side templates on their app servers to generate mostly
static html pages (so no real caching possible).
Using nginx (as you mentioned) seems to be so much better...

The thing that seems "funny" to me is requesting these html
files via URL directly (please see the other answer below)...

Comment: 1. 1) There is no contradiction in using most frameworks and jquery.ready(). 2) I spent some time with Angular.js, it does exactly what backbone creators call "painting you into a corner by making decisions that you're better equipped to make yourself" in their [_why backbone_](http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-why-backbone) section, and it does so sooner than you expect. Unfortunately most other "nice" frameworks seem to do the same. Backbone while doesn't look nice is extremely useful and very easy to learn.

Comment: 2. 1) Generating pages on the server side is both historical and traditional and while it is common, it is not always the case. Only recently browsers became powerful enough to render pages with a satisfactory performance. 
2) You can make your users request (or have links like) http://example.com/app.html but it is not very conventional. The suggested configuration responds with /public/app.html to almost every requested route (say http://example.com/catalog/product/33) and leaves you to implement all application logic in the client.

Comment: 2. 3) You can render pages on the server side and make them cacheable too, although it is an additional headache to manage it, so it is better indeed to avoid it. The drawbacks of rendering pages in the server are a) it uses much more server resources than sending just data, b) you cannot avoid at least some duplication of development effort.
The only reason to render pages on the server side is to make your site crawlable. It makes sense to deliver static content only to headless robots (so I am off to search if I can configure nginx to respond differently to different user-agents :)...

Comment: Awesome - you are doing a super great job here. Thank
you for sharing all the details.

I will definitly look into backbone - thanks for your great expertise.
Really excited now.

Very good point at your second answer and good 
to know about the given routing example. 
Doing it this way makes a lot of sense now.

I totally agree with the crawlable issue... 

kudos!

Comment: Thanks :) I am learning too, no "expertise" :)... And I am still struggling to figure out the right balance/combination of backend/frontend libraries and approaches to deliver what most web apps need (and my web app too :). It's very strange that what exists is either too much (like meteor - still worth having a look - or whatever+angularjs) or too little (like node+connect+express + ??? + jquery+underscore+backbone). Strangely, there is nothing lightweight to bind the latter gracefully. Maybe, I just have to create this missing link as a standalone part of my project...

Comment: There are a soooo many different configurations these days - it's seldom easy to find a suitable solution (which strongly depends on individual conditions anyway). On the other hand all these awesome stuff makes it a great time to be a (web) developer... thats what I like most :) thanks for supporting.

Answer (score 2):

It is not the most common approach but it is still pretty common nowadays. There are many web frameworks ([angularjs](http://angularjs.org) by google, [knockout](http://knockoutjs.com), [moustache](http://mustache.github.com), etc) that work fine with this idea of templates in the client side.

The model is requested to the server (i.e. json) and mapped into a static view (template).

I think it fits really well when you have an API server providing JSON data. This way you can develop just another API client, in this case a web client (RIA). But I don't think the main reason behind this approach is to save CPU.

Comment: Thanks!

I hope angularjs provides a way to help requesting JSON data on initial page loads.

The thing that really baffles/worries me is to call a static html page - as it has been done 10 years ago. But I take it as an accepted way because I cannot think of any other efficient way for better caching.

Calling a certain route on the webapp always implies to talk to the node server (something I only want to do when talking to the database).

If I am wrong or you have some additional ideas please let me know...

PS: Is there any way to look behind the top level domain names
of the big players?

Comment: Depending on the framework. It is not mandatory to get the templates from the server side (you can define them as a 'div' in your page for example), and they can be locally cached in any case. If you are looking for examples of sites using them, take a look at  http://builtwith.angularjs.org (angular). You can find more sites using knockout/backbone as they have been more time in the market.

Comment: Thanks. I will have a look at buildwith.angular.org for sure.
Definitly nice to learn how all these pages use the client side approach (beyond index.html on their initial load) and how they have been inspired by the big players.