# Using JQuery in a MEN Stack Application

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I am building an application using Mongo, Express, Node.js.  I am trying to embed some JQuery inside an .ejs file so that when the user upvotes a post, the score for that post is incremented (or decremented).  I read this post [how to use jQuery installed with npm in Express app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14264429/how-to-use-jquery-installed-with-npm-in-express).  I have included the `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` in my header.  But when I execute my code I get an error that '$ is not defined'.  Here is the relevant portion of the code:

```
              <div class="carousel-inner">
                <!-- Carousel item represents each slide -->
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                  <div class="container">
                    <div class="row align-items-center">
                      <h2>
                        Use Arrow Buttons to Scroll DOWN and UP
                      </h2>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <%   
                  var max = questions.length
                  for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
                %>
                <div class="carousel-item" style="text-align: justify" >
                  <div class="row">
                    <h2><%= questions[i].title %></h2>
                    <p><%= questions[i].body %></p>
                    
                  </div>
                  <div class="row" style="width: 100%; height: 90px; white-space: nowrap; overflow-x: auto;">
                    <p style = "display: inline-block; width: 70%; height: 100%;"><strong>Posted by: </strong><%= questions[i].userid.username %> on <%= questions[i].datePosted.toDateString() %> </p>
                    <button id="submitButton" style = "display: inline-block; width: 30%; height: 50%; border-radius: 5px; background-color:darkcyan" type="submit">View Responses</button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row" style="width: 100%; height: 90px; white-space: nowrap; overflow-x: auto;">
                    <button style = "display: inline-block; width: 25%; height: 50%; border-radius: 5px" id="minus">-</button>
                    <button style = "display: inline-block; width: 25%; height: 50%; border-radius: 5px" is="plus">+</button>
                    <%  relevance = questions[i].upvotes %>
                    <p style = "display: inline-block; width: 50%; height: 100%;" id = "score"><strong>  Score: </strong> <%= relevance %></p>
                  </div>
                  <%
                    var myBoolean = 0;
                    
                    $("#plus").click(function(){
                    
                      if (myBoolean == 0) {
                      relevance++;
                      myBoolean = 1;
                      }
                      $("#score").text(relevance);
                    });
                    
                    $("#minus").click(function(){
                      if (myBoolean == 0) {
                        relevance--;    
                      myBoolean = 1;
                      }
                      $("#score").text(relevance);
                    });
                    
                    %>
                </div>
                <% } %>
              </div>
```

I also want to update my mongoDB database with the updated score using Mongoose, but right now I am just trying to get the basic increment / decrement to work.  I tested all the code OTHER THAN the snippet that starts with <% var myBoolean ... %>.  It all works.  Its just when I try to use the JQuery that this does not work.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: All the code inside `<% ... %>` is backend code evaluated on the server. There you can't use jQuery.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: So, if I just put the JQuery in normal <script></script> tags it would work?  If so, do you know if I can invoke Mongoose to update my database within the <% %> tags?

Comment: Yes, you have to put the jQuery code into the script tags. No, you can't update the database inside this code. This code is a template code to generate frontend code.

Comment: I tried putting the JQuery inside script tags, but it does not appear to work to modify the text on screen when clicked.  Can JQuery work with elements defined in ejs?  If it can't, I am struggling with its utility.  If it can, I don't see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You should post a [mcve]. Currently it's impossible to help.